# Git branch health: check if current branch history is a prefix of the history of the remote tracking branch

Tags: git

Is it possible to determine if the history up to current branch HEAD^ matches a prefix of the history of the remote branch without manual examination of the commit graph?  I am looking for an output that is: true/false.

The motivation for this question is that this strikes me as a good condition to check for the health of my feature branch as I think about automating git workflow.

Comment: What do you mean by “prefix of the history”? Would ‘git branch —merged‘ do?

Comment: The history *is* the commit graph, so given the way this is phrased, you're asking if you can inspect the commit graph without inspecting the commit graph. The answer is pretty clearly "no". Perhaps you mean to ask whether you can, from the command line, tell if one commit is an ancestor of another?

Comment: without analyzing the commit lists -- no. But you can analyze them, look at `rev-list`.

Comment: "without examination of the commit graph", do you mean **manual** examination, or do you mean **any and all** examination **including the one performed by a git command**?

Comment: I mean without manual inspection as Lasse suggests.

Answer (score 3):

I generally use [`git merge-base --is-ancestor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#Documentation/git-merge-base.txt---is-ancestor) which does give a true/false answer.

```
git fetch
if git merge-base --is-ancestor origin/master master; then
  echo "ok: master is the same or has new additional commits on top of origin/master"
fi
```

Comment: I performed an experiment with this where I created a branch.  Initially the merge-base command returns success as expected.  Then I re-based against HEAD~4 reversing the order of the last two commits.  Now the merge-base command returns non-zero exit status as I would hope.  Then I rebase against HEAD~4 to undo the last operation and restore the history order to match origin/master.  The merge-base command given continues to return with a non-zero exit code, defying expectations.  Any suggestions about what is going on here?

Comment: @SetJmp In that case, I usually do a visual inspection of the history, to see what is going on: `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches`

Comment: Using the diagnostic command supplied by @VonC confirms that the hashes of the old commits get modified as part of the rebase.   This does not invalidate his answer to the original question, as it seems a certainty (based on the differing hashes) that pushing to origin in such a state would not succeed if origin enforces no history re-writes (the "[golden rule](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#the-golden-rule-of-rebasing)" of git workflows).  Therefore, a rebase modification like the one I performed strikes me as breaking the health of the feature branch.

Comment: The current solution returns non-exit when the origin/master has moved ahead in commits (despite the commentary in the echo statement).

Comment: @SetJmp "move ahead"? if `master` is behind `origin/master`, then yes, the `git merge-base` will exit with a status different from 0: false.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we should just check if HEAD~ is the merge base:

```
PARENT=`git rev-parse HEAD~`
MERGE_BASE=`git merge-base origin/master ${PARENT}`
if [ $MERGE_BASE != $PARENT ] ; then
  echo 1>&2 "Parent is not the merge base.  Did you attempt to re-write shared history?"
  exit 1
fi
```

A check that HEAD only has 1 parent might also be sensible depending on intent.